# Caching dynamically changing list of objects

Tags: c#, sql, performance, caching, memcached

I have a question about how to efficiently cache list of objects. I have a sample table of `Trip`s. Each `Trip` has `DateFrom` and `DateTo`. I want to cache a list of `Trip`s.

First approach that I consider is getting `Trip`s form database and cache list of `Trip`s ValueObjects (by Value Objects I mean all data needed to display a Trip on a list) at x minutes. This approach is very simple, but have a few disadventages:
 - dealing with pagination - if I store them page by page (for example with key `TripsP1`, `TripsP2`, etc...). When the page size on GUI changes I will have to make a set of Trips with different keys (for example with key `TripsP1Size1`, `TripsP1Size2` etc...)
 - how to deal with sorted list? Keep a set of `Trip`s with different keys for each filters combinations?

Second approach I consider is hittng database for each request but take only `Trip.Id` from database. Next I want to get each `Trip ValueObject` from cache. After creating or modifying the `Trip` I will put them in Cache with `TripId` as key. Also if for some reason I couldn't find `Trip ValueObject` in cache I would take it from database and put into cache.

Which of this to approach is better? Or maybe you can suggest some more efficiently way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why to hold those Trips in form of Pages.

Why not load all the trips into a List (which can be sorted, depends on your needs), and build an in-memory index for Linq search queries? for example [this lib](http://i4o.codeplex.com/).

You can create in memory indexes of your cache for very quick searched, depending on you application query patterns.

If you are worried about Trips being changes while a transaction is in progress (which all caches miss this point), you should implement it using Immutable collection (and make the Trip immutable type).

This way when the user ask the server to provide items with specific criteria, you can easily select those items and provide it a IQueryable (IEnumarable sequence) method for getting streams of data.

Hope this helps, Ofir.